# Mouseover Sensor and Obstruction

Tags: game-engine, mouse

I have a game set up that involves users selecting objects and text.

The text is contained in a separate scene with text objects which are parented to planes that have MouseOver Sensors.

The problem I am having is that if an object appears behind some text, when the user clicks on that text the game selects both the text and the object.

In this case I want the game to only select the text i.e. I want the text object to obstruct the rays to the object.

I imagine there's a setting to do this? But I can't seem to find it...

Comment: would it be possible to do all of it in the same scene?

Comment: Good point! When I originally made it I wanted the text objects to always be visible so I have them in a second scene with a different camera. It would may be easier to have everything in the same scene, but I think would be a bit too annoying to use then.

I think really I should just bite the bullet and work out how to get BGUI working